# Brightness at Macbook 6.1, Lubuntu 13.10, nVidia drivers

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia-graphics-card, lubuntu

I have Lubuntu 13.10 at my Macbook 6.1 (GeForce 9400M video card) - can't make LCD brightness control work with native nVidia drivers (while it works fine with X.Org nouveau driver...).

Tried so far:

1. Used nvidia-173 driver - Xserver doesn't even start
2. Used nvidia-304 and nvidia-304-update drivers
3. Used nvidia-319 driver:

   - nvidia-bl-dkms from mactelPPA - doesn't even installed
   - mbp-nvidia-bl-dkms from mactelPPA (maverick) and pommed
   - *nomodeset* grup param - falls back to the original X.Org driver
   - *acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor* and *acpi_osi=Linux* grub params
   - *acpi_osi='!Windows 2012'* grub param
   - adding */usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia-brightness.conf* with correct settings

and all possible combinations of the above - nothing helps (

Finally found almost my [case](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1833714) (the difference is that mine is not Macbook **Pro** 6.1, it's just Macbook 6.1) - but still doesn't help since I've actually tried that already.

So does anybody know, is it even possible to make LCD brightness controls work with nVidia drivers at Macbook 6.1?? Can't it be because I'm using Lubuntu, not Ubuntu? Any other suggestions 'cause I'm totally stuck (

Comment: Don't have enough reputation yet to provide links to the sources of solutions above in the original post. Will do if required though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally made it myself!
So what solved the problem (*pommed* was already installed):

1. Installed *nvidia-319* driver
2. installed *nvidiabl* (0.85 deb package from https://github.com/guillaumezin/nvidiabl)
   It made _/sys/class/backlight/nvidia_backlight_ device available - still *pommed* used _/sys/class/backlight/apple_backlight_
3. Blacklisted *apple_bl* kernel module
   Added `blacklist apple_bl` to my */etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf*
4. Customized my *etc/pommed.conf* (this step is video card-dependent; e.g. my GeForce 9400M has 0-127 brightness level range)
   *lcd_sysfs* section, `init = 40`, `step = 1`, `on_batt = 20`

And viola! After reboot finally standard MacBook brightness control buttons work like a charm with on-screen display and about 10 brightness levels (for some reason *pommed* translates its `step = 1` in config to 13...)